# Finding unknown in an optimal simplex tableau

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, simplex-method

I have a problem about this simplex problem for my Operations Research class.

The following tableau belongs to the optimal solution of a Linear Programming
Problem. Calculate the value of objective function.

|  | Z | X1 | X2 | S1 | S2 | SOLUTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1/10 | 3/5 | ? |
| X1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1/20 | -1/10 | 4 |
| X2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | -1/40 | 3/20 | 9 |

We are looking for the question mark. If you can teach me how, i would be grateful to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

You can't find the quantity you're looking for without making *some* assumption about the original objective function.  Presumably, the assumption you're supposed to make is that the original objective was a function of $\ x_1\ $ and $\  x_2\ $ *only* (which would be the case, for instance, if $\ s_1\ $ and $\ s_2\ $ were slack variables).  If that's the case, then you can find the original objective function by performing row operations on the tableau to eliminate the entries in the third and fourth columns of the first row.  The entries in the first and second columns of the first row will then be the coefficients of $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $ in the original objective function.  Since you know that the optimal solution is $\ x_1=4, x_2=9\ $, you can now obtain the value of the objective function by substituting those values in the expression you've just obtained for it.